# Adding sound to an iOS app

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to add sound to an iOS app that I am writing.  I keep getting the error message

> "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'contentsOfURL:error:', expected "contentsOfURL:fileTypeHint:')".

I have tried tinkering with it in several ways, and I can't get it to build.  Here is my code:

```
import UIKit  import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var Setup = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DMSetup", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: Setup, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func PlayKeySetup(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }


}
```

Any suggestions?  I'm a newbie at this, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.
xCode 7.3.1, OSX 10.11.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually using uppercase to the properties name it's considered as a bad attitude, you should use `setup`

Try this code:

```
let setupUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DMSetup", withExtension: "mp3")
if (setupUrl == nil) {
   print("Could not find file: DMSetup.mp3")
   return
}
do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: Setup!, fileTypeHint: nil) }
catch let error as NSError { print(error.description) }

if let player = audioPlayer {
     player.prepareToPlay()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("yourfilename", ofType: "format")

let CREATE_ANY_VARIABLE = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: CREATE_ANY_VARIABLE)

} catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }


audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

and then you can play anywhere in the function!
the problem in your code is the name of your var Setup is overlapping with another Setup method form the AVFoundation

Comment: Tried this and ended up with more errors.  Since you said that the problem was with my variable, I changed the name to something less likely to overlap with something else and tried my original code again.  Now I get 1 error message: "Can call throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled."  Any suggestions?